# Angular momentum and rotation symmetry

Tags: classical-mechanics, symmetry, vectors, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

In my book, it is written that for **any** vector $\mathbf{v}$, we have

$$\{\mathbf{v},\mathbf{L}\cdot \mathbf{n}\}=\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{v}.\tag{1}$$

For me it is absurd... For example, if we take $\mathbf{v}=(\cos(x),0,0)$

the Poisson bracket, say we consider $L_z=xp_y-yp_x$:

$$(\{\mathbf{v},\mathbf{L}\cdot \mathbf{n}\})_x=\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial L_z}{\partial p_x}-\frac{\partial L_z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial p_x}+\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}...=-\sin(x)x.$$
I can see that it already fails sincer the left-hand side is $\mathbf{n}\times\mathbf{v}$ can not contain $\sin(x)$...

Or maybe I misunderstood the proposition?

Screenshot of the book's content:

[image]

Comment: could you cite the book?

Comment: Poisson brackets are normally written with curly braces, not square ones.

Comment: @G.Smith isn't curly brackets anticommutator? $\{a,b\}=ab+ba$.

Comment: @Upc Can you still cite the book? A screenshot is not a replacement for a citation. It is more like a replacement for a quotation.

Comment: @Upc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket

Comment: Try it on $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{r}$, or $\dot { \mathbf{r}}$, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Well, there are different notions of [*vectors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) in mathematics and physics.
2. The notion of *vectors* ${\bf v}$ that seems to be relevant here are maps 
   $$\{\text{phase space}\}\times\{\text{time axis}\}\quad\stackrel{\bf v}{\longrightarrow}\quad \mathbb{R}^3$$ 
   that transform in the vector [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of the [3D rotation group $SO(3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group). Here the angular momentum $L_x$, $L_y$, and $L_z$ belong to the corresponding $so(3)$ Lie algebra. OP's eq. (1) is the characteristic property of such vectors ${\bf v}$. [Here ${\bf n}$ is a so-called [rotation vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation), although it is not a vector in above sense].
3. Similarly, [*scalars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(physics))
   $s$ in this context are maps 
   $$\{\text{phase space}\}\times\{\text{time axis}\}\quad\stackrel{s}{\longrightarrow}\quad \mathbb{R}$$
   that transform in the [trivial representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_representation) of $SO(3)$.
4. OP's example does not fulfill eq. (1) and is hence not a vector in the sense of point 2.
5. Similarly, a constant 3-tuple ${\bf v}=(1,-5,2)$ is not a vector in the sense of point 2 because it stays constant rather than rotate under 3D rotations.